# How to create a tag in the corner of a page?

Tags: header-footer

Requested result:

[image: how it should look like]

How to make such a header ("`Fig. 3`") in the left upper corner?

Comment: This would look ugly, in my point of view

Answer (score 1):

The design is your own decision. But, if you need this, then `tikz` is a good choice. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Some text here ...

\begin{figure}[!hbtp]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node at(current page.north west)[anchor=north west,font=\bfseries]{Fig. \ref{fig:f1}};}        
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-A}
\caption{My Figure}
\label{fig:f1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]